# Android Studio not installing application onto my phone

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

So I'm building a flutter app and the app runs perfectly on an emulator and on my friend's Android phones. But refuses to install any apps onto my OnePlus 6 (Android 10). It used to work perfectly about a week ago but randomly stopped installing apps from Android Studio since yesterday.
Yes, I have USB debugging switched on in my Developer Options.
Android Studio just has this running and constantly says its installing build/app but it doesn't go any further. Please help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH2Yh.png)

Comment: run flutter doctor -v and send result

Comment: @dev001 No errors, everything perfect.